How do I create a Notification class that needs to take a navigatorKey but also declare certain functions outside the class?
I made a notification class that will handle background notifications. I was getting this error: Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value, so I moved handleNotificationBackground to outside the class and annotated it with @pragma('vm:entry-point'). This cleared the error.
However, I now have a new problem. The function handleNotificationBackground gives an error pointing to _navigateToScreen. The error is The function '_navigateToScreen' isn't defined. If I try to put it outside the class, then I have to also move the navigatorKey outside, which doesn't work since I need to pass in the key when the class is declared. How do I write this notification class so that it takes in a navigatorKey and also allows the background notifications to work?
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> handleNotificationBackground(RemoteMessage message) async {
  final route = message.data['Screen'];

  _navigateToScreen(route: route);
}

class NotificationService {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  late final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;

  NotificationService({required this.navigatorKey}) {
    _initialize();
  }
  
  Future<void> _initialize() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

    // Set up Firebase Cloud Messaging
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(handleNotificationBackground); //THIS LINE GAVE THE ERROR: Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
    ...
  }

  Future<void> _navigateToScreen({required String route}) async {
    navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed(route);
  }
}

